# Retirar 0 da frente em string Cristal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

Estamos criando um código de barra com o comando:

```
Code128c{(Command.numero)}
```

Porém ele adiciona um `0` que não existe na frente do código. Queríamos retirar este `0`.

Comment: Você poderia informar o número original e número gerado, desse modo teríamos mais elementos para avaliar e responder.

Comment: O número informado (retorno do bd) é 12345.
Quando é realizado este "Code128c..." retorna 012345.

Comment: Afim de outros com uma duvida semelhante a sua possam utiliza-la, sempre e uma boa pratica editar a pergunta e adicionar lá os complementos.

Answer (score 1):

Existe a função MID(string, start_index, end_index) sendo que end_index é opcional, então pode-se utilizá-la da seguinte forma:

```
MID(Code128c{(Command.numero)}, 1)
```